# jQuery and jVal Validation Plug-in. Adding an attribute to an element

Tags: jquery, validation, dom, attributes

I'm trying to add the jVal attribute to a textbox that I created in the HTML.

```
<input id="subJobName" type="text" jval="{valid:function (val) { return validateSubJobName(val); }, message:'Name already exists or is longer than 14 characters.', styleType:'cover'}" />
```

I would let to add /set the jVal in the javascript instead.

2 reasons -

1st : I will not need to search the HTML to see how each item is validated

2nd : We are using a jqGrid and I would like to add this validation to each text box as its dynamically created.

I thought I would be able to removed the jVal from the HTMl to leave me with plain old text box.

```
<input id="subJobName" type="text" />
```

Then in the Doc.Ready function I'd add the jVal to the SubJobName element like so:

```
$("#subJobName").attr({ jval: { valid: function(val) { return validateSubJobName(val); }, message: "Nam", styleType: "cover"} });
```

This doesn't work. I'm not sure if I can even do this ?  Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have jVal 0.1.4 as a work in progress which adds an init() function for what you're looking for. Fetch the latest trunk of jVal.js from http://jquery-jval.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jVal.js.

You can append the jVal and jValKey attributes to fields and then re-initialize the jVal functionality as such:

```
$("#subJobName").attr({ jval: { valid: function(val) { return validateSubJobName(val); }, message: "Nam", styleType: "cover"} });
$.fn.jVal.init();
```